How to make a superscript expression in ggplot2 legend
for some reason the expression I am trying to use for my legend isn't creating the superscript (using ggplot2). Could someone please direct me where I'm going wrong? I need to have the two lines as I want to maximize my plot area.
Reproducible example (although not in ggplot2):
plot(1:1, main=expression(paste('Mean driving\nspeed (km h^-1)')))

Thank you so much

The equivalent ggplot with the superscript using both expression() and ggtext (in the title, subtitle and legend):
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)

df <- tibble(x = 1, y = 1)

df |>
  ggplot(aes(x, y, colour = x)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(
    title = "Mean driving<br>speed (km h<sup>-1</sup>)",
    # subtitle = expression(paste("km", h^-1)), # using expression
    colour = "Mean driving<br>speed (km h<sup>-1</sup>)"
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_markdown(),
    legend.title = element_markdown()
  )


Created on 2024-04-12 with reprex v2.1.0

There's not a way to have it like it is in the main title, but as the legend title? When I try that code for the legend title using labs(fill=), it prints out code as is (with the ><'s etc.)

I've updated the reprex above. Can you try it?

Just realized that element_markdown was a crucial part of the code! (sorry, I wasn't familiar with ggtext). Works perfectly, thank you!!!
